# Web3 Generate QR Payment

Tags: web3js, calldata

I am trying to create a method that allows a user to pay their invoice using ETH. I know in Web3 I can send a transaction, which is handy. But for this to work at the start I want to be able to just generate a QR code that has:

```
Amount: 0.074 eth
Data: (Invoice Number)
```

And the toAddress as that comes to our wallet.

My test code (which is very wrong)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');

// Passing in the eth or web3 package is necessary to allow retrieving chainId, gasPrice and nonce automatically
// for accounts.signTransaction().
export default function handler(req, res) {
    var web3 = new Accounts('ws://127.0.0.1:8551');

    var accounts = new Accounts('ws://127.0.0.1:8551');
   
    

   wallet = accounts.signTransaction({
    from: "(TEST WALLET REMOVED)",
    gasPrice: "20000000000",
    gas: "21000",
    to: "(TEST WALLET REMOVED)",
    value: "1000000000000000000",
    data: "1010020" //INVOICE NUMBER
})

    res.status(200).json(wallet);


}
```

Comment: There were a few attempts at defining a standard, like https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4527. It hasn't been approved yet. Wallet usually only support scanning the QR for the address, but not the amount.

Comment: @Ismael thank you, yeah all we can currently do, is generate new addresses and manage these addresses.